# Error 404 accessing restful service

Tags: java, rest, jboss, ejb

My App Server is Jboss Wildfly 8. I'm going to make my EJB a REST web service.
My EJB:

Interface:

```
@Local
@Path("/books")
public interface BookBeanLocal {
@GET
@Path("/getbookname")
public String getBookName();
}
```

Class:

```
@Stateless
public class BookBean implements BookBeanLocal {

@Override
public String getBookName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "OK";
}

}
```

All of them are put in a Jar as a EJB module.
The Console log says: `Registered web context: /ejb_rest_web`

I'm trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ejb_rest_web/books/getbookname`
but I got Error 404. Why?

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer I think you are confusing the configuration of your web.xml. The documentacion of resteasy in the example about ejb they map the ejb in the web xml as follows

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.jndi.resources</param-name>
  <param-value>LibraryBean/local</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You could see the LibraryBean/local, I think the confusion is about /local, this is part of the mapping that the server does for the statelesbean LibraryBean, so I think you should have:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.jndi.resources</param-name>
  <param-value>BookBeanLocal/local</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's vertainly a lot of error log to have to deal with.

I think there might be a problem in your `web.xml`

```
<param-value>BookBean/Local</param-value>
```

should be

```
<param-value>BookBeanLocal</param-value>
```

no?

Comment: Regarding the document the first one should be used.